# Overlay and Box Opacity Conflict

Tags: css

Using this block of code to create an overlay and a box.

problem: the box is inheriting the opacity of parent and I will like it to have no transparency.

```
#overlay {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      filter:alpha(opacity=50);
      -moz-opacity:0.5;
      -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
      opacity: 0.5;
      z-index: 10000;
      text-align: center;        
    }

    #formed{
      background-color: white;      
      width:300px;
      height:200px;
      position:relative;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
    }

<div id="overlay"><div id="formed">Enter Here</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys. I was able to solve the problem by doing two things:

- Taking the child div outside it's parent.
  `<div id="overlay"></div><div id="formed">Here</div>`
- Altering the positioning of both div's

  ```
  #overlay{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        filter:alpha(opacity=50);
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
        opacity: 0.5;
        z-index: 10000;
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
      }

      #formed{
        /* for IE */
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        /* CSS3 standard */
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
        position: absolute;
        left:50%;
        top:50%;
        margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
        z-index: 12000;
        border: 2px solid #eee;
        display: none;
      }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

That's the way it works, unfortunately. For the parent div, you can try using RGBA for the background color - `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 0):

For something like this (assuming you don't need to support IE7 or earlier), apply the opacity to a pseudo-element as [this fiddle does](http://jsfiddle.net/SRqF8/3/). Code:

**CSS**

```css
#overlay {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 10000;
      text-align: center;        
    }

#overlay:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 0;
}

#formed{
    background-color: white;      
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
    z-index: 1;
 }
```